# Git error when pushing: Object from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded

Tags: git

This has something that's just started happening recently, although I'm not sure what I could have done to trigger it.

Whenever I run a `git push` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/lib/liblm.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

The push does procede after that and works correctly.

I've updated to the latest version of Git (via homebrew) and that didn't solve it.

**EDIT:** Apologies, I wasn't very clear exactly what I was asking. I guess my question is two fold:

- Out of interest, what is causing the error?
- How can I fix the error so it goes away? It doesn't seem to be causing any problems that I can see, but it's a bit irritating!

Comment: Are you pushing to GitHub? I'm getting the exact same error. Asked on #github but no response yet.

Comment: I just noticed this too. Happens only when remote is GitHub.

Comment: That's what I figured since the message was coming through the server response. Must be a configuration mishap in their end.

Comment: Also occurring when doing `git pull` for me.

Comment: This appears to be an issue at GitHub, not a problem on your end. You didn't do anything to trigger it and can't do anything to resolve it, so just ignore the warnings and wait for GitHub to repair things on their end.

Comment: worth a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

Comment: Guestimate from the number of upvotes and people in this question: Working hours started 10 minutes ago in Europe :-)

Comment: This question is not really a good fit for SO, it attracts a lot of me too answers and it's not really possible to answer this question

Comment: Fixed by GitHub :) Try git pull to check it..

Comment: Got the same message, but the fine folks at github.com seem to have fixed it now.

Comment: @Ikke it was not originally obvious that this is a remote issue... It looks like a general system problem, and I for one found this SO page very informative regarding that.

Comment: Yeah, but this question is hardly relevant anymore, fitting the criteria of too localized.

Comment: @Ikke - I think the question "what does this error message mean and why might I receive it" is still relevant. In this particular case, it just happens that the reason for receiving it is unknown, since it's caused by GitHub.

Comment: But all the answers point to a temporal glitch and wont be of any use to anyone coming here in the future.

Comment: This is not that localized, actually. Pretty common thing to run into. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have to assume it's a server mis-configuration. The message is originating from the GitHub server. So rest assured it has nothing to do with your git.

For anyone who cares, here's a good SO explanation for LD_PRELOAD: https://stackoverflow.com/a/426260/591166

**Update**: GitHub has apparently fixed the issue.

Comment: Not fixed just yet... still seeing it here.

Comment: @gulchrider It might be still propagating through their system. Give it a few.